# Why the javascript (w3.sortHTML from w3schools) take so long to run

Tags: javascript, html

I want sort a table in html from the user side... 
Because I guest is will be faster, from the use side, do all data is already there, no need to wait for the server to retrieve the data from database and sort it.
To do this I use the [w3.js](https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js)

```
> w3.getElements = function (id) {
>     if (typeof id == "object") {
>         return [id];
>     } else {
>         return document.querySelectorAll(id);
>     } };



> w3.sortHTML = function(id, sel, sortvalue) {
>     var a, b, i, ii, y, bytt, v1, v2, cc, j;
>     a = w3.getElements(id);
>     for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
>         for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
>             cc = 0;
>             y = 1;
>             while (y == 1) {
>                 y = 0;
>                 b = a[i].querySelectorAll(sel);
>                 for (ii = 0; ii < (b.length - 1); ii++) {
>                     bytt = 0;
>                     if (sortvalue) {
>                         v1 = b[ii].querySelector(sortvalue).innerHTML.toLowerCase();
>                         v2 = b[ii + 1].querySelector(sortvalue).innerHTML.toLowerCase();
>                     } else {
>                         v1 = b[ii].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
>                         v2 = b[ii + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
>                     }
>                     if ((j == 0 && (v1 > v2)) || (j == 1 && (v1 < v2))) {
>                         bytt = 1;
>                         break;
>                     }
>                 }
>                 if (bytt == 1) {
>                     b[ii].parentNode.insertBefore(b[ii + 1], b[ii]);
>                     y = 1;
>                     cc++;
>                 }
>             }
>             if (cc > 0) {break;}
>         }
>     } };
```

script form w3shools function sorthtml
Is work well with a very small amount of data (couple ligne in the table)
But when I try do from a more big table the time to run is really to long to be acceptable.

I'm really a novice in javascript... I try understand why is so long to ru
To reproduce the problem I use the example from w3 to make sure is not my code make this problems but I recopy many time the same amount of data. 

[The example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw_kDFENcCNVSmZCN01PMzFIV1U)

***To have the issue insert a 1000 lines and more.. and you will see***

```
>     <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <title>W3.JS</title> <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>  <body>
> 
> <h2>Sort Tables</h2>
> 
> <p>Click the table headers to sort the  table accordingly:</p>
> 
> <table id="myTable">
>     <thead>    <tr>
>         <th onclick="w3.sortHTML('#myTable', '.item', 'td:nth-child(1)')" style="cursor:pointer">Name</th>
>         <th onclick="w3.sortHTML('#myTable', '.item', 'td:nth-child(2)')" style="cursor:pointer">Country</th>
>     </tr>
>     </thead> <tbody>
>     <tr class="item">
>         <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
>         <td>Sweden</td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr class="item">
>         <td>North/South</td>
>         <td>UK</td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr class="item">
>         <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
>         <td>Germany</td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr class="item">
>         <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
>         <td>Germany</td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr class="item">
>         <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
>         <td>Italy</td>
>     </tr>
>    
> 
> </tbody> </table>
> 
> </body> </html>
```

Comment: You are required to post your code here, not any third party site which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future: [mcve]

Comment: You have a spectacularly inefficient sort algorithm there, which is no more than I'd expect from w3schools. Find a better library.

Answer (score 0):

I use the https://www.datatables.net library to sort is really more efficient.

But I'm still interesting to have the explanation why this simple script is so inefficient...

I will analyse the datable script to see what make it so power full compare to the other one but if somme good samaritain can takes couple minute to explain this script is completely no workable that will be appreciate.

Thanks